# Undefined constant "page_link" (View: \resources\views\home\index.blade.php) In the: "\resources\views/home/index.blade.php" file at line: 19

Tags: php, html, laravel

Hello i need help in this code
Undefined constant "page_link" (View: \resources\views\home\index.blade.php)
In the: "\resources\views/home/index.blade.php" file at line: 19

```
<script>
var url = 'https://wati-integration-service.clare.ai/ShopifyWidget/shopifyWidget.js?84151';
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.async = true;
s.src = url;
var options = {"enabled":true,"chatButtonSetting":{
  "backgroundColor":"#4dc247",
  "ctaText":"",
  "borderRadius":"25",
  "marginLeft":"0",
  "marginBottom":"50",
  "marginRight":"50",
  "position":"left"},"brandSetting":{
  "brandName":"123Albania",
  "brandSubTitle":"Zakonisht përgjigjet brenda një dite",
  "brandImg":"https://cdn.clare.ai/wati/images/WATI_logo_square_2.png",
  "welcomeText":"Pershendetje!\nSi mund te ju ndihmoj?",
  "messageText":"Pershendetje, kam nje pytje rreth {{page_link}}",
  "backgroundColor":"#0a5f54",
  "ctaText":"Fillo biseden",
  "borderRadius":"25",
  "autoShow":false,
  "phoneNumber":""}};s.onload = function() {
    CreateWhatsappChatWidget(options);
};
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
```

Comment: Hello! It seems that this question does not conform to Stack Overflow's quality standards and requires improvements. Make sure to visit the [help], it will teach you [ask] and [answer]. Always try to include a [mre] so that others can help you. And make sure to take the [tour] to learn how StackOverflow works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you call a constant `page_link`. Replace it with `$page_link` :

```
<script>
var url = 'https://wati-integration-service.clare.ai/ShopifyWidget/shopifyWidget.js?84151';
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.async = true;
s.src = url;
var options = {"enabled":true,"chatButtonSetting":{
  "backgroundColor":"#4dc247",
  "ctaText":"",
  "borderRadius":"25",
  "marginLeft":"0",
  "marginBottom":"50",
  "marginRight":"50",
  "position":"left"},"brandSetting":{
  "brandName":"123Albania",
  "brandSubTitle":"Zakonisht përgjigjet brenda një dite",
  "brandImg":"https://cdn.clare.ai/wati/images/WATI_logo_square_2.png",
  "welcomeText":"Pershendetje!\nSi mund te ju ndihmoj?",
  "messageText":"Pershendetje, kam nje pytje rreth {{ $page_link }}",
  "backgroundColor":"#0a5f54",
  "ctaText":"Fillo biseden",
  "borderRadius":"25",
  "autoShow":false,
  "phoneNumber":""}};s.onload = function() {
    CreateWhatsappChatWidget(options);
};
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
```